# Conversion of Eaton provided MIBs into pysnmp format

Tags: pysnmp, ups

I want to log the details provided by Eaton UPS like batteries health, input/output voltage and other important details.
I want to use Python "pysnmp" module to automate the process. However the supported MIBs provided by Eaton UPS website is not getting converted into pysnmp format.
We need your expertise to find out the ways to fetch the required details from Eaton UPS using python or others if any.